# How can I execute multiple filters on top of each other in react-admin?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I'm using `react-admin` to manage the admin dashboard for my firebase API. Currently I'm trying to add multiple filters to my admin dashboard which include search, verified email and others. I've written multiple filters as such

```js
const UserFilter = (props) => (
  <Filter {...props}>
    <TextInput label="Search" source="phoneNumber" alwaysOn />
    <BooleanInput label="Email Verified" source="emailVerified" alwaysOn/>
  </Filter>
);
```

and using it as

```js
<List {...props} filters={<UserFilter />} />
```

But when I'm trying to filter, then these filters are not applied on top of each other. They are applied as `OR`. So if I use two filters the results are those with either one of those and both. I want the filters to be applied as `AND`. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Your filter results depends on the api endpoint that you provide to the `dataProvider` prop.

When you try to filter for - say `username` equals `bret`, a request is made (you can check n/w tab) with the query params.
For example, like this:

`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?_end=10&_order=ASC&_sort=id&_start=0&username=bret`

So your backend will read the params and returns the filtered results. In your case your api endpoint always does `OR` not `AND`. Hence the issue.

One way to solve is to simply adjust your backend which returns `AND` results.

Other hack is to [extend the DataProvider](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#extending-a-data-provider-example-of-file-upload) and override `getList` function and manipulate the api results based on your requirement.

```js
import simpleRestProvider from 'ra-data-simple-rest';

const dataProvider = simpleRestProvider('http://path.to.my.api/');

const myDataProvider = {
    ...dataProvider,
    getList: (resource, params) => {
        // custom getList function
    ...
```

See the [source code of getList](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/89ac783fd9f961401d1c2e8d4ca4965053ed1d21/packages/ra-data-simple-rest/src/index.ts) to copy the function code and adjust it based on your needs